# Questions on creating a MultiBoot CD/DVD

Tags: live-cd

I just found a way which is used to crate a MultiBoot(Multiple disto) on a CD/DVD. I have found it from here **multicd.tuxfamily.org**. I followed all the steps given on the site but I am stucked after multicd.sh extracts the iso. It downloads a file **syslinux-4.05.tar.gz** which has a size of approx. 6.14 MB. The download always fails and thus the .iso is not created. I separately download that file. Now how can I tell the multicd.sh to not download the file but use this file which I downloaded. Please help.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting syslinux in the same directory as the shell script and running my slightly modified version:

http://parodicaltech.tk/multicd.sh

Apologies for having to use my webserver.
If it fails, then make sure that it is that the working directory contains both multicd.sh and syslinux-4.05.tar.gz
I have not tested this script, unfortunately, although it should work.

Comment: Hey, I done the same thing as you said but I am getting this error "Unpacking and copying files...
./multicd.sh: line 2052: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

Comment: After editing the script myself it worked...

Comment: @ravi OK... what was the problem?

Comment: I got this error "Unpacking and copying files... ./multicd.sh: line 2052: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'"

Comment: @Ravi Sorry if I was unclear, but I wanted to know where I had made a mistake so I avoid it next time.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a empty dir `mkdir /tmp/multicd`;
- Go to the newly created dir `cd /tmp/multicd`
- Next issue this command, it will download the latest multicd.sh `git clone git://git.tuxfamily.org/gitroot/multicd/multicd.git`
- Now download the ISOs you want combined on the Multiboot CD/DVD and put it
  in the dir with the correct name; see here for supported ISOs http://multicd.tuxfamily.org
- For example get caine.iso `wget http://www.caine-live.net/Downloads/caine2.5.1.iso`
- Download other ISOs
- Finally run `./multicd.sh`
- This will now create a file multicd.iso

Comment: Hi I just want a modified multicd.sh file which can use my downloaded syslinux-4.05.tar.gz so I don't have to download from the terminal.....

Comment: What is wrong with running the 5 commands above? It is simple!

Comment: When I run ./multicd.sh it works fine but after extracting iso it download syslinux file which always fails to download. so the whole process fails. I want a modified multicd.sh which can use the already downloaded syslinux.tar.gz.

Comment: So the problem is that you can't download the latest syslinux.tar.gz file. Does this work for you:
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/boot/syslinux/syslinux-4.05.tar.gz

Comment: Hi I separately downloaded syslinux.tar.gz. Now how to edit the script multicd.sh so that it will use the already downloaded syslinux.tar.tz. I hope you understand....! Or please provide a alternate method to make a multi cd....

Comment: If you already have a syslinux.tar.gz, multi.sh should not even try to download it again. Can you ping www.kernel.org?